# Usando interpolação de string C# 6

Tags: c#, interpolação-de-string

Com o C# 6 e o uso a interpolação ficou melhor de concatenar string com dados.

Como no exemplo.

Ao invés de:

```
var d = "19";
string.Format("{0} anos", d);
```

fica bem melhor

```
$"{d} anos";
```

Porém usando o recurso, criei uma coluna na minha base de dados no qual será alimentada pelo usuário através de objeto.

Tenho um objeto imóvel com suas propriedades.

Ao realizar a interpoção direta como:

```
$"{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel";
```

Funciona perfeitamente.

Porém agora eu tenho essa informação `"{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel"` em uma coluna.

E através de um `foreach` eu preciso que funcione, alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Ex:

```
var imovel = new Imovel().GetImovel(); // aqui retorna meu objeto imovel
foreach(var t in Textos){
 var meuTexto = $""+ t; // aqui tem isso "{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel"
 var TextoInterpolado = meuTexto; // aqui deveria formatar Casa1 aqui é meu imóvel, mas ele mostra apenas assim "{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel"
}
```

Não sei se ficou muito claro, mas desejo algo como neste exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zk3nbL

Comment: A resposta é simples: Não pode fazer isso desse jeito. Mas pode ser feito [deste jeito](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqPtx2)

Answer (score 3):

segue o retorno esperado, um amigo respondeu por email.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listaImoveis = new List<Func<Imovel,string>>{
            imovel => $"{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel",
            imovel => $"{imovel.Numero} aqui é meu imóvel",
            imovel => $"{imovel.Complemento} aqui é meu imóvel"
        };      

        var imovelVai = new Imovel { Nome = "Casa X", Numero = "10", Complemento = "Casa X"};       
        foreach(var t in listaImoveis)
            Console.WriteLine(t(imovelVai));
    }
}

public class Imovel
{   
    public string Nome{ get; set; }
    public string Numero{ get; set; }
    public string Complemento{ get; set; } 
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/b15fYK

Comment: Igual ao que eu postei à 23horas atrás como comentário à sua pergunta. Parece que ele chegou à mesma solução que eu, uma vez que o meu fiddle não tem visualizações.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Bruno Costa, não vi seu comentário, por que não postou como resposta direta? Mas é isso mesmo, vc matou a charada!

Answer (score 2):

Você quer obter o valor do objeto normalmente, mas o nome da variável deve ser igual ao nome que você tem em seu texto, por exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listaImoveis = new List<Imovel>{
            new Imovel{Nome = "Casa1"},
            new Imovel{Nome = "Casa2"},
            new Imovel{Nome = "Casa3"}
        };
        //var imovel = new Imovel{Nome = "Casa4"};
        //  foreach(var t in listaImoveis){
        //  var texto = $"{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel";
        //  Console.WriteLine(texto);
        //}

        foreach(var imovel in listaImoveis){
            var texto = $"{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel";
            Console.WriteLine(texto);
        }
    }
}

public class Imovel
{
    public string Nome{get;set;}
}
```

Neste exemplo, está substituindo o valor da lista, mas se descomentar o código, irá ver que ele também recupera o valor do objeto fora da lista, basta ter o mesmo nome da propriedade que está passando no texto.

[Veja funcionando no .NetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GBT9UH)

A forma que você está concatenando o texto que não funciona: `var meuTexto = $""+ t;`. Ele tenta aplicar a *interpolation* antes do sinal de `+`, ou seja, antes do texto `{imovel.Nome}`.

Comment: Eu sei como funciona a interpolação. Mas entenda minha situação. no seu foeach, você percorre os imoveis e printa na tela. Já no meu, eu percorro uma lista de strings, que seguindo seu exemplo seria: "{imovel.Nome} aqui é meu imóvel", "{imovel.Numero} aqui é número do meu imóvel". Entendeu?

Comment: Como neste exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zk3nbL

Comment: @IvanTeles Então edite a sua pergunta e explique isso. Da forma que está, não da para entender que deseja isso.

Comment: Randrade adicionei o exemplo da minha necessidade, consegue me ajudar com alguma ideia?