# Verificar se ficheiro com nome dinâmico existe no disco

Tags: c#, io

O meu programa gera um ficheiro XML com o nome a seguir a seguinte estrutura:

> C:/caminhoDosFicheiro/NOMEQUENAOMUDA_data_nrDeElementosNoXML.xml

De momento, eu cada vez que gero um ficheiro e ele tem o `nrDeElementosNoXML` diferente do `nrDeElementosNoXML` do ficheiro já existente, cria-me mais um ficheiro. Posso usar algum método para apagar o ficheiro que já la está antes de criar um novo? Algo deste género:

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:/caminhoDosFicheiro/NOMEQUENAOMUDA_data_*valorDesconhecido*.xml"))
{
    File.Delete(@"C:/caminhoDosFicheiro/NOMEQUENAOMUDA_data_*valorDesconhecido*.xml");
}
```

Comment: Antes de inserir um novo, você quer apagar todos os existentes que iniciam com "NOMEQUENAOMUDA_data_"?

Comment: exatamente, queria ver se alguém sabe uma técnica simples, pois eu tenho algumas ideias de como fazer, mas tenho quase a certeza que não são as melhores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute a eliminação com o auxilio do [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) utilizando o filtro desejado no [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/caminhoDosFicheiro");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles("NOMEQUENAOMUDA_data_*.xml"))
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
```

Existem outras maneiras também, pode conferir neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory) (SOen).

Comment: Funcionou 5*. No meu caso tive de usar esta lógica para obter os ficheiros corretos: 

`di.GetFiles(_key + "_" + globalDateToDownload.Date.ToString("yyy_MM_dd") + "_*.xml")`

Comment: Tente usar interpolação, fica mais legível e inclusive, muito mais simples de escrever. Ficaria assim sua linha: `di.GetFiles($"{_key}_{globalDateToDownload.Date.ToString("yyy_MM_dd")}_*.xml")` http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128043/usando-interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-string-c-6

Comment: não conhecia essa técnica, está muito melhor assim! vlw